# ExpressionEngine access via both http and https

Tags: expressionengine

We have an ExpressionEngine site we’re accessing via both http and https.  Our users get security warnings from IE when accessing via https because some assets are accessed insecurely (CSS and images referenced there, in this case).

This happens when the setting ‘General Config -> URL to the root directory of your site’ includes the http:// protocol identifier (With that field blank, set just to the site domain [example.com], or set without a protocol [//example.com/], we encounter other problems, so those are not really an option).  The problematic URLs are, of course, those generated with {path=} or {stylesheet=} in the templates.

Is there a good way to get all assets delivered via the same protocol as the page?

Thanks,
Scott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because EE variables don't detect or utilise https by default, so you have to set them in code. The easiest way is to use an add-on:

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/https-support

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/dm-force-ssl

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/force-ssl (commercial)

(In no particular order) I've not used any of these so can't recommend a specific one as I use my own plugin.

Comment: OK, awesome -- HTTPS Support is exactly what I was looking for.  It's a nice, simple extension which resets EE's 'base_url' (among others) in your session if accessing via https.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to include the root URL?  Often times I'll set the root URL of a site to just '/'.

Another option would be to manually include those assets (not using path or style helpers).

If a URL is realtive it will automatically inherit the current protocol.

Comment: When I use '/', saving entries in the Control Panel breaks -- specifically, the Pages module complains about a bad URL.  And yes, I could manually code the URLs, but the point here is to keep the advantages of {path=} and friends.

Answer (score 0):

You can detect the protocol with PHP and set it dynamically in your `system/expressionengine/config/config.php` file. I use something like this:

```
$protocol = (isset($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) && $_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") ? "https://" : "http://";
$base_url = $protocol . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

$config['base_url'] = $base_url . "/";
```

You can build your theme paths, various image paths, upload paths, etc all from that basis in `config.php`. But `$config['site_url']` is what affects the output of `{path=""}` and `{stylesheet}` tags.

For more information, see [NSM's Config Bootstrap file](http://ee-garage.com/nsm-config-bootstrap) or the article [Configuring ExpressionEngine for multiple servers](http://old.kennwilson.com/2007/11/configuring-expression-engine-for-multiple-servers). For all the paths you can set in `config.php`, see [EE2 Config Overrides](http://expressionengine.com/wiki/EE_2_Config_Overrides)

Comment: thanks for some more great options.  For simplicity, [HTTPS Support] (http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/https-support) does this in a small extension; it also deals with site_url and a few other less-common settings out of the box, which is cool.  I like the idea of doing this in config.php, or something required from there, though, and am tucking it into my toolbox!